# API Integrity issue?

Tags: api, asana

I think it may be an issue with the integrity of the information presented in the Asana Web API.

Through the Asana app im seening a task as a subtask (parent_id !=null).
But using the API, when i fetch for that project tasks, im geting that task (which it is actually a subtask).

Anyone know what could be happening?

As a hint, fecthing that task, i see that it belongs to a project, which has been its owner, but it now belongs to the one i asking for subtasks.

**References:**

Project_id: 4877424416407 (task listed as a task, which it is actually a subtask)

Task_id: 5764340212513

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtasks are first-class tasks and can belong to projects in their own right. So, for example, if task A has subtask B, and subtask B is in project P, then when you fetch tasks for project P, you will get B in the results. Does this map to what you're seeing, or is the subtask not explicitly in the project you requested?

Comment: Now i see what you say. 
I have a project P with a task P1 and a another project Q, with a task Q1 with a subtask P1. That made a mess to my mind.

Thank you!